# How does regeneration work in Magic the Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-regenerate

How does regeneration work?

I know that if my creature is destroyed then I can spend X mana then tap my creature and move it out of combat. Is it attackable in any way after that? With spells or instants?

If someone for example casts [Shock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShock%5d) on my [Manor Skeleton](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bManor%20Skeleton%5d), can I say in response “Ok, I will spend 2 mana to regenerate it”? Or does Shock immediately resolve to destroy the creature (assuming it has no regeneration shield on it)?

Comment: After reading your edit, I think [this article on Priority and the Stack](http://mtgsalvation.com/794-priority-and-the-stack.html) may be helpful for you. After the Shock is played you have priority to respond.

Comment: @AdamArold, Your link is down.

Comment: @Pacerier AdamArold isn't the one who provided the link, and if you notice a broken link, it's way more helpful to everyone if you just take a couple seconds to figure out how to fix it: http://www.mtgsalvation.com/articles/15678-priority-and-the-stack

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A creature is destroyed when a resolved spell or effect says so (destruction by effect), or when the total damage it received this turn from anywhere is equal to or greater than its current toughness (destruction by game rules).

At any time you can regenerate a creature with an appropriate spell or effect. The only condition is that the regeneration has to happen before the destruction effect. You can regenerate a creature as often as you like, anytime. For each time you regenerate it, the creature gets a "regeneration shield" that lasts until the turn ends or until it is used up by a destruction effect, whatever happens first. If a destruction event would happen and the creature has a "regeneration shield" active, the following things happen:

- One of those shields is removed
- All damage received by the creature this turn is removed
- If a destruction effect caused the event to trigger, it resolves but has no effect
- The creature gets tapped (Note that this is an effect of regeneration. The creature does not have to be untapped to regenerate it)
- The creature gets removed from combat, if it was regenerated during combat

Note that certain spells or effects state something like "Destroy target creature. It can't be regenerated.". In that case, you can still respond with a regeneration shield, but the regeneration effect is ignored and the creature still gets destroyed.

> Is it attackable in any way after that? With spells or instants?

"Attack" has a defined meaning in M:TG: You attack with creatures only, during a combat phase. The only valid targets for an attack are opposing players and Planeswalkers.
The correct term to use for spells and effects is "target", if it is a targeted spell or effect.
And yes, regeneration provides no further protection from multiple damage sources or spells/effects. You can, as stated above, provide multiple regeneration shields, so as long as you can pay the costs, you can regenerate as often as you want.

Comment: @edem Regarding your edit: Both Shock and the regeneration ability, as all spells and effects, use the stack. Therefore a Shock never resolves immediately, and you can always respond to it, unless (as always) another effect or ability prevents you from doing so. For example, as long as a spell with the *Split Second* ability is on the stack, nobody can put other spells/effects on the stack.

Comment: @Hackworth, So "regeneration" is a misnomer and should have been called "double life".

Comment: When do triggered abilities that say "when this creature regenerates" occur? Do they occur when a shield is used up or when a shield is created?

Comment: There are many descriptions of what happens. An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Responding to your edit:

> What I really wanted to know is that if someone uses for example Shock
>   on my creature can I say at that moment "Ok, I will spend 2 mana and
>   regenerate my creature" or when that Shock is played it is resolved
>   immediately any my creature is destroyed (assuming that it has 1
>   toughness and no regeneration shield on it)

How the rules of Magic work is as follows:

Your opponent pays 1 red mana and casts Shock.  Shock is now placed "on the stack".  Assuming that neither you nor your opponent want to play any spells or abilities in response, Shock "resolves", your creature takes 2 damage, and, assuming its toughness is 2 or less, goes to the graveyard.

However, you *do* want to do something, which is regenerate your creature!  With Shock on the stack, you say "in response, I regenerate" and pay your mana. This puts the ability on the stack, on top of Shock. Now, assuming neither you nor your opponent want to play any more spells or abilities, the objects on the stack start to resolve from top to bottom (LIFO), thus the ability resolves first and a regeneration shield is created.  Now Shock is at the top of the stack; assuming neither you nor your opponent want to play any more spells or abilities, it resolves, and your creature is dealt 2 damage, though this time it survives thanks to the replacement effect provided by its regeneration shield.

Here's an interesting case for you: your opponent casts Shock on your creature.  In response, you tap two lands, and use your creature's regeneration ability.  In response to *this*, your opponent taps for another red mana and casts **another** Shock from his hand!  You may at this point be out of mana and unable to respond by using the regeneration ability again.  In this case your creature is toast, despite trying to regenerate, as the second Shock will resolve before anything else...

Hope this helps you visualise how the stack works - it's quite hard until you suddenly "get it", and then it's pretty easy, I promise you!

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. By the way can a regenerate effect be countered by - for example - a blue player who has a lot of counters? And if he counters it can I cast regenerate again for 2 additional mana?

Comment: @edem - Regeneration isn't a spell, so it can't be countered by most blue counters (which say "counter target spell").  It *can* be countered by a spell which says "counter target activated ability", e.g. a Stifle.  And yes, if some counters your regeneration ability with Stifle there is nothing to stop you regenerating again, either in response to the Stifle or after it has resolved.

Comment: It is a creature ability I think. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @edem It's still an activated ability, if it has a cost preceding a colon on the card.  The other type of ability is a triggered ability ("When [x], [do y]").  An activated ability can appear on any type of permanent, including creatures.

Comment: Oh yes, and there are static abilities, which are basically the ones that are "always on".  But all abilities fall into one of those three categories, including all creature abilities :)

Comment: @AdamArold, There are **spells** that do regeneration too: https://www.google.com/search?q=regenerate+target+creature&tbm=isch . Those can be countered.

Comment: @thesunneversets, So for the scenario you've outlined, is the Regeneration's target located in the graveyard or is the target considered undefined?

Comment: @Pacerier Regenerate is only useful for creatures on the battlefield. There is (almost) always time between someone **announcing** a spell or ability that could kill your creature and the creature dying. In face to face play that isn't always apparent because the rules specifically allow shortcuts that **both** players agree.

Answer (score 3):

> What I really wanted to know is that if someone uses for example Shock on my creature can I say at that moment "Ok, I will spend 2 mana and regenerate my creature"

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: I linked [this nice article](https://www.mtgsalvation.com/articles/15678-priority-and-the-stack) as a comment to your question that has a very thorough discussion, with examples, of how the Stack and Priority works in MtG. I thought I'd give the summary here. Note in this synopsis I will ignore any rules, cards or keywords that may modify these rules. (ie. [Split Second](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Split_second), [Flash](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Flash))

1. When a player plays a spell or ability, that player keeps priority. The Spell/Ability is on the stack but *doesn't resolve yet* (ie. Shock).
2. When a player with priority passes priority with a Spell/Ability on the stack, the next player may play an [Instant](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Instant) or activate an ability (ie. regenerate).  If they do, it goes on the **top of the stack** but *doesn't resolve yet*.
3. The Spell/Ability **on top of the stack** resolves when both (or all, in multiplayer games) players pass priority in a row.
4. When a spell resolves, the active player (the player whose turn it is), gets priority. If there are still spells or abilities on the stack, go to step 2.

And just to be crystal clear, once the Regeneration Shield resolves (replaces a destruction effect) that card *can still be targeted again*. If your opponent has another Shock and has mana, he can cast the spell on your creature. Of course, if you still have the mana, you can regenerate it again…

Comment: Another useful visualisation exercise could be a creature with "U: This cannot be the target of spells or abilities till end of turn".  If you successfully resolved this in response to a Shock, the Shock would "fizzle" (be countered by game rules).  But someone could still cast a Shock in response to this ability being played, and potentially kill the creature before the ability resolved...

Comment: @thesunneversets, What if the rules collide with each other? E.g. you play "This cannot be the target of spells or abilities till end of turn", in response to that, he plays "This can always be the target of spells or abilities till end of turn". Then who wins?

Comment: @ghoppe, So does the regeneration shield only works once? E.g. you tap a creature giving it regeneration. When *that* resolves, I play shock. Shock resolves, then I play another shock yet again. What happens?

Comment: @thesunneversets, What if the rules collide with each other? E.g. **1)** you play "This cannot be the target of spells or abilities till end of turn", in response to that, he plays "This can always be the target of spells or abilities till end of turn". Then who wins? **Or 2)** I stack shock, you stack regenerate, i stack wrath of god which says "creatures cannot be regenerated", then you stack "all creatures can be regenerated". Who wins?

Comment: @Pacerier Regeneration is a replacement effect that means: *the next time this permanent would be destroyed this turn, it isn't. Instead tap it, remove all damage from it, and remove it from combat.* Therefore, it can only replace one instance of being destroyed. If you play a second shock, I must have some way to regenerate it again or it is destroyed.

Comment: @Pacerier Comprehensive Rule [**101.2**](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats): *When a rule or effect allows or directs something to happen, and another effect states that it can’t happen, the “can’t” effect takes precedence.* Remember, the stack is resolved in last-in first-resolves order.

Answer (score 1):

The way regeneration works is that, when a creature is regenerated, it receives protection from the next effect that would put it into the graveyard equivalent to the "destroy" action. So, if your creature would receive lethal damage or be targeted by a Doom Blade or something, you can activate regeneration, and when the effect occurs, the destruction part of the effect is ignored, and instead the creature is tapped, if it wasn't already. (So a creature with lethal damage has the damage removed, but the creature remains in play.) The regeneration "shield" only protects against the first such effect; if your creature has two toughness and there are two Lightning Bolts on the stack targeting it, you'll need to activate its regeneration ability twice to keep it from dying. Regeneration also doesn't protect against effects that exile the creature, sacrifice effects, or effects that specify that the creature is destroyed and cannot be regenerated.